# SAP BO Freehand SQL date formatting (Oracle db)

Tags: oracle, performance, date, business-intelligence, sap

My original query worked perfectly via SQL Developer:

`select * from [table] where DT_CURRENT_DT = '15-OCT-18'`

However when ran via freehand SQL in SAP BO I got no results.
After running the query with no conditions I noticed that BO re-formats the date to `10/15/18`

Answer (score 0):

`to_date` function solved the issue and now the condition is recognized by BO's freehand SQL.

`DT_CURRENT_DT = to_date('10/15/18', 'MM/DD/YY')`

Comment: Better use `to_date('10/15/18', 'MM/DD/RR')` or **much** better `to_date('10/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')` - did you never hear about the [Y2K-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)? - (I see I am getting old. Nowadays developers were still young kids when the Y2K topic was all over in the news)

Comment: Always use 4-digit years.  The 'RR' trick is a band-aid fix for the Y2K problem.  If you read the Oracle documentation, The answer can change at the year `2050`.

Comment: I prefer standard ISO date literal: `date '2018-15-10'`